# draw an ellipse or contour in matlab

Tags: matlab, draw

I have two vectors a = [1 1]' and b = [1 -1]' which are linearly independent.
I want to draw a shape like an ellipse or a contour around these points, so I can see the area which is spanned by these two vectors.

The picture below shows what I want to get. One of the blue vectors belongs to a and one of the red to b (I drew the mirrored vectors also for demonstration purpose). The green circle is what I want to draw.
[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: You could try to try something first.

Comment: I did. I used the contour function but I have no idea how I can use it for my case. But it uses matrices instead of vectors (okay, a vector is also a matrix). As I put both vectors in I got an error that Z has to be at least a 2x2 matrix. I don't know what data has to go to Z. I want the contour just 2 dimensional. For me, the documentation (found here: http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html) is not very helpful.

Comment: Well, at least draw an example picture of what you actually want. It is very unclear.

Comment: The `contour` function is not what you need for a simple ellipse. Just define a set of `x` and `y` points which respect the [ellipse equation](http://www.mathopenref.com/coordgeneralellipse.html) `(x/a)^2 + (y/b)^2 = 1`, then use the simpler `plot(x,y)` function. Try that, if it still doesn't work edit your post by showing what you've tried and you'll get better help.

Answer (score 0):

From your question and your example it seems to me that you don't have an entirely clear idea what you are trying to do. In order for MATLAB to plot anything, it will need at least a collection of points or an equation according to which this ellipse you want can be plotted.

The cleanest way to do so in this case would be to find the equations defining the ellipsoid. Using the information seen [here](http://www.mathopenref.com/coordparamellipse.html), we see that we can describe any 2D-ellipse centered on the origin by the following equations:

```
x = a*cos(t)
y = b*sin(t)
```

The question then is: what should the values for our parameters `a` and `b` be? Since we have two points given that should satisfy these equations: [1,1] and [1,-1] we can deduce that `a` and `b` are equal to the square root of 2. Then we can plot the contour:

```
syms t              % our equation's parameter is t

a = sqrt(2); b = sqrt(2);

x = a*cos(t);
y = b*sin(t);

ezplot(x,y)         % plot the symbolic equation
```